# ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED when allowing https traffic to dataiku instance on GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, https, virtual-machine, dataiku

I installed dataiku on GCP instance.

It works perfectly fine on http protocol.

Now I am trying to allow https traffic.

I followed this official doc: https://doc.dataiku.com/dss/latest/installation/custom/advanced-customization.html#configuring-https

But after doing all the mentioned steps, I have an `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` on my browser when doing: `https://MyDataikuInstanceIp:1024`

Is something more required on GCP in order to allow https traffic on the instance ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to allow https and http traffic on a GCP instance, you should follow the next steps:

1. Navigate to Compute Engine > VM Instances.
2. Select your instance. Go to Edit.
3. Scroll down and locate Firewalls. Check both "Allow HTTP traffic" and "Allow HTTPS traffic".
4. Save your instance.

To review whether the firewall rule is enabled or disabled, you can use the following command:

```
gcloud compute firewall-rules describe [FIREWALL-NAME]
```

Also, if you have created a network tag in your instance, you will need to associate it to your firewall rule to match the target.

In the following [link](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-firewalls#updating_firewall_rules), you will find more information about how the firewall rules work in GCP

In addition as a best practice check if the firewall on your client is allowing connections through the `TCP ports 443,1024`  and the certificate from your server domain was allowed in your client.